# Twitter Digits - Find Friend Feature not Working

Tags: ios, twitter, twitter-digits

The find friend feature with Twitter Digits is not working for me. I've followed all the steps in the documentation, but I'm not able to find my friend, despite having his # in my contacts.

Is this a known issue? I have literally copy and pasted the code from the [docs](https://docs.fabric.io/ios/digits/find-friends.html).

**Edit:** I just tried reproducing the issue by creating a completely empty, clean project, adding in Fabric and Digits, ran the app on two separate real devices each with its own set of contacts (but A in B's contacts and B in A's). I still get 0 friends...